# Is there a way to sign commits that originate from github.com?

Tags: git, github

#### Background

When "Vigilant Mode" is enabled and a commit is made in github.com, the commit is marked unverified/unsigned and everyone can see it (not just users with vigilant mode enabled). This is a problem because some repos only allow signed commits, but only users with "Vigilant Mode" enabled are blocked (specifically when the commit originates from github.com).

Is there a way to sign commits that originate from github.com?

#### Repo Steps

How to enable "Vigilant Mode:

- github
- profile icon
- settings
- SSH and GPG Keys
- Enable "Vigilant Mode" checkbox

How to see an unverified commit:

- Open an already merged PR
- Click the "revert" button near the bottom
- Create a draft PR
- Open the "commits" tab

Comment: How are you creating the commit on GitHub?  There are several situations in which GitHub does sign commits it makes, so you do need to be specific about the way you're making the commit.

Comment: @bk2204 I am seeing unsigned commits when I attempt to revert a merged PR (steps outlined in the question).

Comment: It's probably the case that GitHub doesn't support signing revert commits at the moment and you'll need to do it from the command line.

Comment: Interesting - I just attempted to edit our README in github.com and the commit is signed, you're probably right then.